# What is wrong with my reasoning in this differentiation under the integral sign problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Let $y(t)$, $f(t)$ be $C^2$-functions satisfying $y(x) = 4\int_0^x(t − x)y(t)dt−\int_0^x(t − x)f(t)dt.$
>
> Show that $y$ solves the differential equation $y''(x) + 4y(x) = f(x)$, with the initial conditions $y(0) = 0, y'(0) = 0$.

I used differentiation under the integral sign, and got the following-

$y'(x)=4[0-0+\int_0^x\left(\frac\partial {\partial x}(t-x)y(t)\right)dt]-[0-0+\int_0^x\left(\frac\partial {\partial x}(t-x)f(t)\right)dt]=$

$=-4\int_0^xy(t)dt+\int_0^xf(t)dt$

Now, I could have gone on and do a second derivation, but I came upon this confusing thought- $y(t)=4\int_0^x0dt-\int_0^x0dt=0$ so $\int_0^xy(t)dt=\int_0^x0dt=0$, and then $y'(x)=\int_0^xf(t)dt$.

This ruins the rest of the calculation. If I would have ignored that, I would get to the correct final result.

My question is, was is wrong with saying $y(t)=0$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your mistake is that you are ignoring the limits of the integral when you differentiate. What is the derivative of $y(x)=\int_0^x t\,dx$? Hint: it is not zero.

Comment: @uniquesolution - how are the limits of integration relevant when the insdie of the integral is zero?

Comment: Well, they just are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "$t$" in $y(t)$ cannot be the same "$t$" inside the integral.

The "$t$" inside the integral is a dummy variable of integration and has no independent existence, so it is definitely **NOT** correct to think you have "$(t-t)y(t)$" under the integral.

Answer (score 1):

The symbol $t$ was used as both a parameter AND a dummy integration variable.  In the first case, it is a fixed number, $x=t$, while in the second it spans all numbers between $0$ and $x$.  Therefore, they mean compmetely different things.